# Externalize Spring Boot property file with Jboss and multiple war

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, properties-file

I have two .war (Spring Boot application) deployed on the same Jboss instance.
Both of them have their application.properties file.

Now I need to externalize these files, let's say in two different path:

```
/myPath/warA/application.properties
/myPath/warB/application.properties
```

I know there is the possibility to define system properties in the standalone.xml like so:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="spring.config.location" value="{pathToConfigDir}"/>
</system-properties>
```

But this works only with one property file.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.